# PHP Comparing Variables

Tags: php, variables, post

I have many variables sent from a voting form. i want to check and make sure no two values on the form are equal. How can i do this?

```
<?php
$Name = $_POST['name'];
$ID = $_POST['id'];
$Topic_1 = $_POST['1'];
$Topic_2 = $_POST['2'];
$Topic_3 = $_POST['3'];
$Topic_4 = $_POST['4'];
$Topic_5 = $_POST['5'];
$Topic_6 = $_POST['6'];
$Topic_7 = $_POST['7'];
$Topic_8 = $_POST['8'];
$Topic_9 = $_POST['9'];
$Topic_10 = $_POST['10'];
$Topic_11 = $_POST['11'];
$Topic_12 = $_POST['12'];
$Topic_13 = $_POST['13'];
$Topic_14 = $_POST['14'];
$Topic_15 = $_POST['15'];

if($_POST != $_POST)???
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and [pass the values from the form as an array](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) instead of each one individually. It would then be trivial to determine if you have a duplicate with `count($arr) == count(array_unique($arr))`.

Comment: @Jon I think you should put that in an answer, as that is indeed the most sensible thing he could do.

Comment: @Sumurai8: I didn't really intend to, but since you brought it up... ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily determine if any array contains duplicate values with the construct

```
if (count($array) === count(array_unique($array))) {
    // contains duplicates
}
```

This is true for any array, including `$_POST`. So if you want to make sure that all 15 fields plus the name and id are unique with respect to one another, substitute `$_POST` for `$array` above and you are good to go.

There are a few more things you might want to keep in mind here:

1. If it's possible that some of the form elements will be left blank and you are OK with allowing multiple blank fields then you need to remove them from the array before making the duplicate check. This can be done with (just one possible way):

   ```
   $array = array_filter($array, function($i) { return strlen($i); });
   ```
2. If you want to look for duplicate among only a subset of the form elements, then the most consequent way is to make this subset an array of its own. You can have PHP do this automatically for you by [naming the form input elements appropriately](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays).
3. Related to the concept of uniqueness is the function [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php), which can be useful in similar circumstances (it can tell you how many duplicate elements there were and exactly what their value was).

Comment: It worked thanks. i never knew about this.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST != $_POST

would definitely not work, cause this tests if the same variable is not the same variable.

You have to loop trough the $_POST array

```
<?php
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    foreach($_POST as $subKey => $subValue) {
        if($key != $subKey && $_POST[$key] == $_POST[$key])
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is following

```
$_POST['1'] = 'a';
$_POST['2'] = 'b';
$_POST['3'] = 'c';
$_POST['4'] = 'a';
$_POST['5'] = 'd';

$results = array_unique($_POST);
var_dump($results);
```

returns:

```
array
  1 => string 'a' (length=1)
  2 => string 'b' (length=1)
  3 => string 'c' (length=1)
  5 => string 'd' (length=1)
```